# Active State disappears when I click on a non-active link and switch tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's a strange issue I'm having with my code's active state, that only appears when I click on another link and then switch  tabs:   http://fiddle.jshell.net/3nafff9d/

[image]

**To replicate my problem you must do the following:**

1. Run the JSFiddle above at **769 width** for the menu to show up.
2. Notice that All the "**active**" list items are blue, and by default the the **Call Me link** is selected on all the tabs you switch to.
3. Now click on the next link the **Log link** until you see the active state color of blue.
4. Now click on the another tab, and you'll notice that all of a sudden the active state has been removed from the menu. Now no items are blue.

Now my question is: **How can I change the code so that the active state color: blue is remembered even when you switch tabs or select another list item?**

**JS:**

```
//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav2 a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav3 a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav4 a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Custom Toggle  
$('input[name="intervaltype"]').click(function () {

    $('#Custom').toggleClass('active');
    $('#Types').toggleClass('active');
});

//Custom Toggle  
$('input[name="intervaltype2"]').click(function () {

    $('#Custom2').toggleClass('active');
    $('#Types2').toggleClass('active');
});

//Custom Toggle  
$('input[name="intervaltype3"]').click(function () {

    $('#Custom3').toggleClass('active');
    $('#Types3').toggleClass('active');
});

//Custom Toggle  
$('input[name="intervaltype4"]').click(function () {

    $('#Custom4').toggleClass('active');
    $('#Types4').toggleClass('active');
});


//Check and Uncheck
$(".checkAll").click(function () {
    $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

//Check and Uncheck Below-2
$(".checkBelow").click(function () {
    $(".checkother").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

//Custom Check and Uncheck All-2
$(".checkAll2").click(function () {
    $(".check2").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

//Check and Uncheck Below-2
$(".checkBelow2").click(function () {
    $(".checkother2").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});


//Check and Uncheck 3
$(".checkAll3").click(function () {
    $(".check3").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

//Check and Uncheck Below-3
$(".checkBelow3").click(function () {
    $(".checkother3").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

//Custom Check and Uncheck All-4
$(".checkAll4").click(function () {
    $(".check4").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});

//Check and Uncheck Below-4
$(".checkBelow4").click(function () {
    $(".checkother4").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});



//Selection Active       
$( '.servicelist a' ).on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
  if ( !$(this).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
    $( '.servicelist .active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( '.servicelist a[href="' + $(this).attr( 'href' ) + '"]' ).parent().addClass( 'active' );
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper2">

         <!-- Sidebar -->
   <div class="topfilter">

     <div class="tabber">

   <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="servicelist" role="tablist">

    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 serviceop active" role="presentation">
    <a href="#construction" aria-controls="construction" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="fa-2x fa fa-home"></i>
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="serviceop col-md-3 col-xs-3"  role="presentation">
    <a href="#precon" aria-controls="precon" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="fa-2x fa fa-info-circle"></i> 
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 serviceop" role="presentation">
    <a href="#generalcon" aria-controls="generalcon" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="fa-2x fa fa-briefcase"></i> 
    </a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 serviceop" role="presentation">
    <a href="#builddesign" aria-controls="builddesign" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
    <i class="fa-2x fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
    </a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div> <!-- End Tabber-->
</div><!-- End Topfilter-->

</div> <!-- End sidebar-wrapper 2--> 


   <!-- Tab panes -->
 <div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="construction"> 

<div id="sidebar-wrapper3">

             <li class="toppy" role="tab" style="list-style:none;">
            <label data-target="#Custom"> <span class="customtext">Choose</span>    
                <input name="intervaltype" class="check checkAll chix" type="checkbox" />
                       </label>
        </li>


</div>                       
<div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-wrapper">


   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav">

     <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">

      <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check checkBelow"> Settings
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check checkother"> Log out
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check checkother">Profile
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check checkother"> Account
    </label>
  </div>

  </div><!-- End Form-group -->
  </form>

   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->

        </div> <!-- End Tab Panel-->


  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="active highlight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseZero"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk">
                            </span>Call Me</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div><!-- End Panel-Heading -->



 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="highlight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>Log</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div> <!-- End Panel-Heading -->

       <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <li>
      <a class="highlight" href="#/content">
       Loglines
       </a>
      </li>
       </div>  <!-- End CollapseOne -->


    <div class="bottomfilter">
   <a href="#" class="filtertitle">Terms</a>    

   </div>  <!-- End Bottom Filter -->


  </div> <!-- End Panel Default in Accordion -->

   </div><!-- End Accordion -->


    </div> <!-- End Panel Default -->


   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->


   </div> <!-- End Types 1 -->


    </div> <!-- End SideBar Wrapper 1 -->

</div> <!-- End Tab Panel -->

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="precon">
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper3">

             <li class="toppy" role="tab" style="list-style:none;">
            <label data-target="#Custom2"> <span class="customtext">Choose</span>    
                <input name="intervaltype2" class="check2 checkAll2 chix" type="checkbox" />
                       </label>
        </li>


</div>                       
<div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-wrapper">


   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom2">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav2">

     <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">

      <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check2 checkBelow2"> Settingz
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check2 checkother2"> Log outz
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check2 checkother2">Profile
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check2 checkother2"> Account
    </label>
  </div>

  </div><!-- End Form-group -->
  </form>

   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->

        </div> <!-- End Tab Panel-->


  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types2">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav2">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#bcollapseZero"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk">
                            </span>Call Mez</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div><!-- End Panel-Heading -->


 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="highlight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#bcollapseOne"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>Logz</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div> <!-- End Panel-Heading -->

       <div id="bcollapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <li>
      <a class="highlight" href="#/content">
       Loglinez
       </a>
      </li>
       </div>  <!-- End CollapseOne -->


    <div class="bottomfilter">
   <a href="#" class="filtertitle">Termz</a>    

   </div>  <!-- End Bottom Filter -->


  </div> <!-- End Panel Default in Accordion -->

   </div><!-- End Accordion -->


    </div> <!-- End Panel Default -->


   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->


   </div> <!-- End Types 1 -->


    </div> <!-- End SideBar Wrapper 1 -->

</div> <!-- End Tab Panel -->



      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="generalcon">

 <div id="sidebar-wrapper3">

             <li class="toppy" role="tab" style="list-style:none;">
            <label data-target="#Custom3"> <span class="customtext">Choose</span>    
                <input name="intervaltype3" class="check3 checkAll3 chix" type="checkbox" />
                       </label>
        </li>


</div>                       
<div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-wrapper">


   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom3">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav3">

     <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">

      <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check3 checkBelow3"> Settingz
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check3 checkother3"> Log outz
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check3 checkother3">Profile
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check3 checkother3"> Account
    </label>
  </div>

  </div><!-- End Form-group -->
  </form>

   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->

        </div> <!-- End Tab Panel-->


  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types3">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav3">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#ccollapseZero"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk">
                            </span>Call Mez</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div><!-- End Panel-Heading -->


 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="highlight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#ccollapseOne"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>Logz</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div> <!-- End Panel-Heading -->

       <div id="ccollapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <li>
      <a class="highlight" href="#/content">
       Loglinez
       </a>
      </li>
       </div>  <!-- End CollapseOne -->


    <div class="bottomfilter">
   <a href="#" class="filtertitle">Termz</a>    

   </div>  <!-- End Bottom Filter -->


  </div> <!-- End Panel Default in Accordion -->

   </div><!-- End Accordion -->


    </div> <!-- End Panel Default -->


   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->


   </div> <!-- End Types 1 -->


    </div> <!-- End SideBar Wrapper 1 -->

</div> <!-- End Tab Panel -->


 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="builddesign">
 <div id="sidebar-wrapper3">

             <li class="toppy" role="tab" style="list-style:none;">
            <label data-target="#Custom4"> <span class="customtext">Choose</span>    
                <input name="intervaltype4" class="check4 checkAll4 chix" type="checkbox" />
                       </label>
        </li>


</div>                       
<div class="tab-content" id="sidebar-wrapper">


   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Custom4">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav4">

     <form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">

      <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check4 checkBelow4"> Settings
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check4 checkother4"> Log out
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check4 checkother4">Profile
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="check4 checkother4"> Account
    </label>
  </div>

  </div><!-- End Form-group -->
  </form>

   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->

        </div> <!-- End Tab Panel-->


  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="Types4">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav4">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="active highlight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#dcollapseZero"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk">
                            </span>Call Me</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div><!-- End Panel-Heading -->



 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a class="highlight" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#dcollapseOne"><span class="iconpad glyphicon glyphicon-user">
                            </span>Log</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div> <!-- End Panel-Heading -->

       <div id="dcollapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <li>
      <a class="highlight" href="#/content">
       Loglines
       </a>
      </li>
       </div>  <!-- End CollapseOne -->


    <div class="bottomfilter">
   <a href="#" class="filtertitle">Terms</a>    

   </div>  <!-- End Bottom Filter -->


  </div> <!-- End Panel Default in Accordion -->

   </div><!-- End Accordion -->


    </div> <!-- End Panel Default -->


   </ul> <!-- End Sidebar Nav-->


   </div> <!-- End Types 1 -->


    </div> <!-- End SideBar Wrapper 1 -->

</div> <!-- End Tab Panel -->

</div> <!-- End Tabs Content -->
```

**CSS:**

```
a {outline:none !important;}

html,
body,
.wrap {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  height: 100%
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
  /* for sticky footer to not go below page */
  /* for sticky header to not overlap content */
}

.push,
.footer {
  height: 60px;
}



.footer {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;   
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 0;
}


#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 142px;
height:95%;
  width: 0; bottom:0; top:65px;
  height:auto; border-top:1px solid #fff;
  margin-left: -142px;
  overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:hidden;
  background: #eee;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper2 {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 142px;
  top:0; 
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;
  min-height:55px;  height:auto; 
  margin-left: -142px;
  background: #eee; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


#sidebar-wrapper3 {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 142px;
  top:35px; 
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width:auto;
  min-height:55px;  height:auto; 
  margin-left: -142px;
  background: #eee; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.filtertitle { position:relative; display:inline-block; color:#000; width:auto; }

.topfilter { max-width:100%; min-width:100%; position:relative; display:inline-block; min-height:65px;  }

.tabber {bottom:0px !important; height:auto; left:0;  position:relative; display:inline-block; border-bottom: solid #fff 1px; }

.customtext {color:#666;}

.toppy {bottom:0px !important; text-indent:9px; }

.bottomfilter {border-top: solid #666 1px; width:100%; height:auto;  position:relative; display:block; text-align:left; background-color:#eee;  }

.checkbox {margin-left:25px !important;}

.dropdown { margin-top:15%; display:inline-block; }

.dropdown a {margin-left:20px; min-width:100% !important;  }

.caret {text-align:right !important; position:relative;}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 200px;  
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper2 {
  width: 200px;  
}


#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
}

   #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -200px;
}



@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 300px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }


  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width:1526px) {

  .content,
  .footer {
    width: 82%;
    right: 0; 
  }
  .header {width:82%;}

    #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 18%; 
  }
    #sidebar-wrapper2 {
    width: 18%; 
  }

}


@media screen and (max-width:1059px) {

  .content,
  .footer {
    width: 80%;
    right: 0; 
  }

  .header {width:80%;}

    #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 20%; 
  }

     #sidebar-wrapper2 {
    width: 20%; 
  }
}   

     @media screen and (min-width:1527px) {

  .content,
  .footer {
    width: 85%;
    right: 0; 
  }
  .header {width:85%;}
    #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 15%; 
  }

     #sidebar-wrapper2 {
    width: 15%; 
  }


}

        @media screen and (max-width:991px) {
          .content,
  .footer {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0; 
  }

  .filtertitle {display:none;}

    #sidebar-wrapper {
    width:0;   
  }

    #sidebar-wrapper2 {
    width:0;   
  }
  .topfilter {width:0; display:none;}

.dropdown a {display:none;}



}

.iconpad { margin-right:10px; }
.panel-body { padding:0px; }
.panel-body table tr td { padding-left: 15px }
.panel-body .table {margin-bottom: 0px; }

.panel-title a:hover {color:#333; text-decoration:none;  background:none !important;}

.panel-title a:focus {color:#39f; text-decoration:none; background:none !important;}

.panel-title a {text-decoration:none; background:none !important;}







/* Service list - Top Sidebar Icon Nav */

.servicelist {  list-style:none; padding:0; }

.servicelist a{ background:none !important; text-decoration:none; color:#333;  list-style:none; }

.servicelist a :hover {  color:#bdc3c7;  }

.servicelist > li.active > a .fa-2x {
color:#f90;
   cursor: pointer;
}






/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:inherit; min-width:100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px; 
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666; 
  background:#bdc3c7;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav a.active {
color:#39f;  background-color:#eee;   } 

/* Sidebar Styles 2*/

.sidebar-nav2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:inherit; min-width:100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav2 li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px; 
}

.sidebar-nav2 li a {
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666; 
  background:#bdc3c7;
}

.sidebar-nav2 li a:active,
.sidebar-nav2 li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav2 a.active {
color:#39f; background-color:#eee;    } 


/* Sidebar Styles 3*/

.sidebar-nav3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:inherit; min-width:100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav3 li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px; 
}

.sidebar-nav3 li a {
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav3 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666; 
  background:#bdc3c7;
}

.sidebar-nav3 li a:active,
.sidebar-nav3 li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav3 a.active {
color:#39f; background-color:#eee;     } 


/* Sidebar Styles 3*/

.sidebar-nav4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width:inherit; min-width:100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav4 li {
  text-indent: 20px;
  line-height: 40px; 
}

.sidebar-nav4 li a {
  display: block; 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav4 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666; 
  background:#bdc3c7;
}

.sidebar-nav4 li a:active,
.sidebar-nav4 li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav4 a.active {
color:#39f; background-color:#eee;     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your code is binding an event listener to each one of these links and then using `$(this)` to apply the active class after wiping all links of any classes. While that works on a tab-by-tab basis, it will only add that class to that specific element in that specific tab. So when the user clicks the first "Call Me" link, it's marked active and when they switch tabs, a brand new "Call Me" link is shown, but since the event listener added the class to only the item that was clicked, it doesn't have the active class added to it.

You could simply apply the active class to the same elements under all other tabs, e.g., when a user clicks the first "Call Me" link, make all "Call Me" links active.

If you actually want to remember state (which links are active, etc.) then the best route would be to store this information and perform logic based on that. Where to store it is a matter of how your page is supposed to function. If it's just short term you can simply keep it in a variable or in session storage. If it's going to be across multiple browsing sessions then you could go for local storage.

**Edit:**

If I understand correctly, then it might be easier to add a `callMe` class to all of the "Call Me" links, and a `log` class to all "Log" links, then remove:

```
//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav2 a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav3 a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.sidebar-nav4 a').click(function() {
    $('a').removeClass();

    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

and just use:

```
//Selection Active       
$('.callMe').click(function() {
    $('.log').removeClass('active');

    $('.callMe').addClass('active');
}); 

//Selection Active       
$('.log').click(function() {
    $('.callMe').removeClass('active');

    $('.log').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Each tab should be independent this includes the active state, and it should remember the last active tab.  I'm still learning the ropes, so how can I edit the js to make it remember the state depending on the tab?

Comment: @ChosenJuan please see my edit and hopefully that will help

Comment: The above solution won't work, because I must add multiple links not just callme and log, and the links all have to be independent of each other. So if I select log on the first tab, then the second tab should still be default call me until I change it.